# Wine 2.0 over 1.8 version

Tags: wine

I just installed Wine 1.8 via Software Center on Ubuntu 16.04 and then realized that there is a newer release. What should I do to install this? First remove the previous version? The tutorials which describe the installation of Wine 2.0 don't mention it.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the commands to terminal, if you got a folder .wine which is your current installation will be renamed to .wine_BACKUP:

```
    mv ~/.wine ~/.wine_BACKUP
    wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
    sudo apt-key add Release.key
    rm ./Release.key
    sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ -y
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
    sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging -y
    sudo apt-get install winetricks -y
    winecfg
```

enjoy